# Can collision events in Unity run in parallel?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say a trigger raises 2 simultaneous collision events, is there any chance they'll both run the same OnTriggerEnter() method in parallel? Or will they always run it one after the other? Any reason to use thread-safety mechanisms (like lock) in this case?

Comment: Unity API basically runs all in one single thread. So no not in parallel .. you can't predict the order though

Answer (score 2):

OnTriggerEnter always sends information about the collider it hit as a method parameter. If two collisions occur at the same time, they will be called one after the other.

Comment: Thanks! Does it say in the official documentation that 2 collisions must run one after the other? The collider information is quite irrelevant if OnTriggerEnter() runs twice at the same time and I need to maintain a common database after each collision. I want to avoid a race condition situation.

Comment: @yyy Both of the answers have told you what happens. It is not possible for two collisions to happen at the exact same time. As mentioned, Unity is single threaded. No two things can happen simultaneously on a single thread.

Comment: Asyranok is right. Since unity code is executing on a single thread, it is not possible to receive two method call at the same time, so there is going to be 2 calls one after the other. If you want to add the collision to a database, you can compare the colliders from both calls and if they're the same, add it once. You're not really clear on what you want to acheive but it's possible to know if it's the same collider that's been it in the 2 method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is not multi-threaded or asynchronous. Everything is sequential. Unity uses Coroutines instead of async to simulate async to the human eye, but it is really just running chunks of code up to the next "yeild" statement in a Coroutine. The exception to this is when you explicitly program asynchronous logic. In those cases, you must handle locks yourself. Unity has been working on better async support for a few years now though.

Every Coroutine script attached to an active game object has one of these chunks of code run, one after another, until the required logic runs for each game object. So as far as the human eye is concerned, all objects are interacting at the same time (assuming the code is well optimized).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't asking about coroutines (even though it is interesting to know how they work under the hood). I'm asking regarding collisions that happen at the exact same time. I know Unity simulates threads with coroutines so I'm worried it might do the same thing for collusions somehow. If everything is indeed sequential then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Unity is **not** thread safe  - this is why it runs all sequential in one single thread ;)

Comment: @yyy I mentioned coroutines to explain why async and multithreading are not used in Unity -> because Coroutines simulate it. My point is that Unity uses a single thread, and thus no collision can possibly happen at the exact same moment as another collision.

Comment: @derHugo I meant that Unity uses a single thread, which I said. A single thread is technically thread safe, even if that is not typically called that. Because it cannot lock with another thread if no other threads are used. Just call that semantics.

Comment: Removed comment about thread safety though as that is reasonably misleading.